# Apache BeanUtils > Can I register a generic converter for any Enum implementation?

Tags: java, enums, apache-commons-beanutils

I have the following `genericEnumConverter` which can convert any `String` object it to it's respective `Enum`.

Is there a way I can register the converter, for **any** `Enum` class, rather than having to explicitly register each `Enum` (e.g. use the parent `Enum` class)?

```
ConvertUtilsBean convertUtilsBean = new ConvertUtilsBean();
PropertyUtilsBean propertyUtilsBean = new PropertyUtilsBean();
BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean = new BeanUtilsBean(convertUtilsBean, propertyUtilsBean);

// custom converter = String->Enum
Converter genericEnumConverter = new Converter() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> T convert(Class<T> type, Object value) {
        if (type.isEnum()) {
            return (T) Optional
                .ofNullable(value)
                .map((v) -> Enum.valueOf((Class<? extends Enum>) type, v.toString()))
                .orElse(null);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
// explicitly defining an Enum implementation works...
convertUtilsBean.register(genericEnumConverter, FoobarEnum.class);

// but having a generic parent Enum class doesn't...
convertUtilsBean.register(genericEnumConverter, Enum.class);
```

@scottb:

Because the converter is generic, it can take any Enum class. e.g.

```
private enum Foobar1 {CAT, DOG}

private enum Foobar2 {APPLE, BANANA}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(genericEnumConverter.convert(Foobar1.class, "DOG")); // DOG
    System.out.println(genericEnumConverter.convert(Foobar2.class, "APPLE")); // APPLE
    System.out.println(Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(Foobar1.class)); // true
    System.out.println(Foobar1.class.isAssignableFrom(Enum.class)); // false
}
```

How might the `BeanUtilBean` know which converter to use? It know's if the target class (e.g. `Foobar1`) is assignable to an `Enum`.

Comment: I've written an API for converting enums using the JPA Converter facility.  The problem with writing a generic converter class that will convert to/from any enum class is that Java generics are erased at run time.  Type safety with Java generics is largely a compile-time only phenomenon.  Unless you have a concrete converter class for each enum type you wish to convert, how could your generic converter know which enum type to use?

Comment: @scottb - see updated section. The `BeanUtilBean` should have access to all the information it requires...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to Enum using Apache BeanUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904592/convert-string-to-enum-using-apache-beanutils)